# django-admin cannot find settings file?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Currently I have 3 django projects and they share some common settings like `database_engine`. I created a folder `settings` to house the settings for each project. I have

1. top_settings.py: settings shared
   among the 3 projects
2. site1to3_settings.py: common
   settings inherited from top_settings
   and site_specific settings

Question: how do I put these in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` so that I can work with `syncdb` and other commands on each project with django-admin.py? I already have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` pointing to these files in my respective wsgi files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import settings from other files using the 'from x import *' statement.

Set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the site specific setting file and in that include

```
from top_settings import *
```